# colour detection bot

Tags: image-processing, macros, pixel, bots

I want to create a script to automatically click on a moving target on a game.

To do this I want to check colours on the screen to determine where my target is and then click him, repeating this if he moves.

I'm not skilled at programming and there might be an easier solution to what I have proposed below:

1/Split the screen into equal tiles - size of tile should represent the in game object.

2/Loop through each pixel of each tile and create a histogram of the pixel colours.

3/If the most common recorded colour matches what we need, we MIGHT have the correct tile. Save the coords and click the object to complete task

4/Every 0.5 seconds check colour to determine if the object has moved, if it hasnt, keep clicking, if it has repeat steps 1, 2 and 3.

The step I am unsure of how to do technically is step 1. What data structure would I need for a tile? Would a 2D array suffice? Store the value of each colour in this array and then determine if it is the object. Also in pseudo how would I split the screen up into tiles to be searched? The tile issue is my main problem.

EDIT for rayryeng 2:

I will be using Python for this task. This is not my game, I just want to create a macro to automatically perform a task for me in the game. I have no code yet, I am looking more for the ideas behind making this work than actual code.

3rd edit and final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import win32gui, win32api

#function to take in coords and return colour

def colour_return(x,y):
    colours = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), x,y)
    return colours

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

#variable declaration
x = 1
y = 1 
pixel_value = []
colour_found = 0

while x < 1600:
    pixel_value = colour_return(x,y)
    if pixel_value == 1844766:
        click(x,y)
    x=x+1
    #print x
    print y
    if x == 1600:
        y=y+1
        x=1
        #print tile
        pixel_value = 0
```

This is the final code that I have produced. It works but it is incredibly slow. It takes 30 seconds seconds to search all 1600 pixels of y=1. I guess it is my method that is not working. Instead of using histograms and tiles I am now just searching for a colour and clicking the coordinates when it matches. What is the fastest method to use when searching an entire screen for a certain colour? I've seen colour detection bots that manage to keep up every second with a moving character.

Comment: You haven't provided the language / paradigm that you're using to do this.  Also, what do you have so far? Do you have something already set up, and is this a function that you call within your game?

Comment: If you ultimately want to represent each tile as a histogram, just make it a 1D array of colours.  However, you're going to have to figure out what amount of quantization you need to figure out how many colours you want as doing a colour histogram is a bit more difficult to deal with.  How would you compute similarity between histograms for colour? With grayscale it's more intuitive.